# Still sending the fail message even when i have the role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if(!host || !Sadmin){
    msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
    msg.channel.send(hostmsg).then(hostmsg => hostmsg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))
}else {
    msg.channel.send(suc)
    msg.guild.channels.create(name, {type: 'text'})  
}
```

so i have the host role but it still send the hostmsg not the  sucsess message

Comment: What is `host` and `Sadmin`?

Comment: Have you checked your variables `host` and `Sadmin`? Try sending them and look what is inside. For example before this `if` you can try: `msg.channel.send(JSON.stringify({host: !!host, Sadmin: !!Sadmin}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much context, so this is somewhat a guess. But I think what you want is for the `hostMsg` to be send if the user doesn't have the host or Sadmin role.

However, the `if` statement you have checks for whether you don't have the `host` role OR don't have the `Sadmin` role. So unless you have BOTH the `host` role AND the `Sadmin` role, it will send the `hostmsg`. Changing the `||` to `&&` will make it so if you have either the `host` or the `Sadmin` role, it will send the `suc` message.